# Why doesn't the JavaScript work for Firefox/Chrome but for IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I've written a simple JavaScript to add options to an HTML Select element, the code looks like this:

```
 function addOption() {
    var newOption = document.createElement('<option value="TOYOTA">');


    var elSel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    try{
    elSel.add(newOption,null);
    } //Standard
    catch(ex)
    {elSel.add(newOption);
    } //IE Only
    newOption.innerText = "Toyota";
}
```

I found online tutorial that shows we need to do something like this to get both Firefox/Chrome and IE work. However, currently only IE will work, for FF/Chrome, when I click on the "Add" button, nothing is added to the dropdown, could anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
mySelect.add(new Option("Toyota", "TOYOTA"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to specify the node name, not an HTML string ala jQuery style to `createElement` afaik.

```
var el = document.createElement('option')
  , fc = document.createTextNode('blah')
  , s = document.getElementById('foo');

el.value = 'blah';
el.appendChild( fc );
s.appendChild( el )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do a lot of UI manipulation, I suggest using a 3rd party library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make this easier and more cross-browser compatible.

```
 $('#mySelect').
      append($("<option value='TOYOTA'>TOYOTA</option>").
      attr("value",'TOYOTA').
      text('TOYOTA'));
```

Comment: I agree, there is no need. I said "I suggest" due to the increased browser compatibly of UI manipulation in general.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that even works in IE.

Try replacing everything inside the function with this:

```
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.setAttribute("value", "TOYOTA");
newOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode("My toyota"));
var elSel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
elSel.appendChild(newOption)
```